# postgresql function call from java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have very strange issue. I design one function which is inserting values into postgresql table. But when I try to call that function from java at that time it seems like did not insert. Even I am not getting error as well. My code is below.

```
String query = "{call postgres.addToLog(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

    try{

        CallableStatement ps = getPostgresConfiguratoin().prepareCall(query);

        ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
        ps.setInt(2, 705);
        ps.setInt(3, 1);
        ps.setInt(4, 1);
        ps.setString(5, "192.168.2.101");
        ps.setString(6, null);
        ps.setString(7, query);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my call?

Comment: Missing `commit()` maybe?

Comment: But when I try to debug application at that time object ps shows me select query and then call but function has only inser query then why it tries to get select query? That is one more strange thing I noticed.

Comment: What does the PG log file say? There you should see the actual `UPDATE` statement as it reaches the server, or at least any errors that the statement generates.

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick. Log file checking really helpful to me. I figured out my mistake. Really really thank you so much.

Comment: @RAJPATEL  Since you found your mistake, you should add an answer to your question and accept it so that future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I found in logs that my function insert query has one column name which has wrong spelling so my insert query never insert anything. After furthermore research I found out that as best practice to provide exception handling into PL-SQL as well. I provide Exception handler into my PL-SQL block and it return error which I can see on my Java program side as well.